# How to print a certain ASCII character on Linux terminal using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, ascii, gnome-terminal

I need to run C++ code on Linux terminal, one of the requirements is to print character 220 of ASCII, when I wrote `cout<<char(220)` and did run it on Windows console, it worked as expected, but in Linux, the character doesn't appear.

Comment: There is no character 220 is ASCII, it only goes up to 127. Windows console uses code pages to provide characters above 127. What character is displayed depends on what code page the console is set to use.

Comment: Most Linux distributions use utf-8, you need to find the utf-8 code sequence for the character you want to print. Note that `220` isn't an ASCII character

Comment: What specific symbol do you want to print? Where do you want the output to go? Outputting the byte 220 (0xDC) on a Linux terminal emulator is unlikely to produce anything useful, because (as others have said) the terminal emulator is likely to use UTF-8, and 0xDC is not, on its own, a valid single byte in UTF-8. It might produce something meaningful on the Linux text console, because that probably uses CP437, like MSDOS, so there will be some overlap with Windows code pages. This subject is more complicated than it might initially appear.